# How to judge that the vertices's order of polygon is clockwise or counterclockwise?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, computational-geometry

The concrete question is:

> n lines, each line containing two integers. The i-th line contains xi, yi — the i-th vertex of the polygon in clockwise or counterclockwise order. Note that it is possible that more than two vertices appear in a side, such as the follow picture:
>
> [image]
>
> Now you need to judge that the vertices's order of polygon is clockwise or counterclockwise?

c++ code is:

```
struct Node
{
    int x, y;

    Node operator-(Node node) const
    {
        Node t;
        t.x = x - node.x;
        t.y = y - node.y;
        return t;
    }

    int operator*(Node node) const // I konow this is Cross-Product
    {
        return x * node.y - y * node.x;
    }
}node[1000];

 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     scanf("%d %d", &node[i].x, &node[i].y);

 int tmp = 0;

 node[n].x = node[0].x, node[n].y = node[0].y;

 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     tmp += (node[i] * node[i + 1]);

 if (tmp > 0)
        it is counterclockwise order;
```

But I don't understand the code, who can prove it?

Comment: What do you mean that "each line containing two integers"? A line is defined by two endpoints, each of which is defined by two numbers. Do you mean each *point* has integral coordinates? (That's what it seems from your code.)

Comment: @Rory Daulton Yes. Each point has integral coordinates.

Comment: @RoryDaulton: I assume “line” in the problem description refers to line of text, i.e. row.

Comment: @MvG: Ah, yes, the OP left out the beginning of the problem description, and the "line" is an *input* line. That makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) will give the *oriented* area of any polygon. By examining its sign, you can therefore determine the orientation. The code you have does compute twice the area, but as the sign is all that matters, this is irrelevant.